# Red5 stream audio from Azure Storage or Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-storage, red5

I'm wondering if its possible to stream audio in Red5 from files stored in Azure? I am aware of how to manipulate the playback path via a custom file name generator IStreamFilenameGenerator, our legacy Red5 webapp uses it. It would seem to me though that this path needs to be on the local red5 server, is this correct?

I studied the example showing how to use Amazon S3 for file persistence and playback (https://goo.gl/7IIP28) and while the file recording + upload makes perfect sense, I'm just not seeing how the playback file name that is returned is streaming from S3.  Tracing the StringBuilder appends/inserts, it looks like the filename is going to end up to be something like {BucketLocation}/{SessionID}/{FileKey} ... this lead me to believe that bucket.getLocation() on Line 111 was returning an HTTP/S endpoint URL, and Red5 would somehow be able to use it.  I wrote a console app to test what bucket.getLocation() returned, and it only returns null for US servers, and EU for Europe.  So, I'm not even sure where/how this accesses S3 for direct playback.  Am I missing something?

Again, my goal is to access files stored in Azure, but I figured the above Amazon S3 example would have given me a hint.

I totally understand that you cannot record directly to Azure or S3, the store locally + upload makes sense.  What I am failing to see is how to stream directly from a blob cloud storage.  If anyone has suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Any update on this? I am looking for the same

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Azure Media Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/)? I believe looking at their [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/media-services/) will be a good start for your scenario.